# Turn a ruby array into a neat column string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm new to ruby, and I'm trying to make a program that automates formatting for given strings and arrays. One autoformat function I'm trying to figure out is one for arrays. So let's say I have an array like the example below

```
myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and I want to turn it into a columnized string so that `puts myString` will give

```
`1) a`
`2) b`
`3) c`
```

How would I go about doing this? The closest thing I can find is using `.each` which isn't what I want, I can't have each line a separate entry. It all has to be one string with line breaks.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What about this `myArray.each_with_index.map {|i, j| "#{i+1}) #{j}"}.join("\n")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-map) with [`.with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

myStr = myArray.map.with_index(1) { |el, i| "#{i}) #{el}" }.join("\n")
puts myStr
```

Outputs:

```
1) a
2) b
3) c
```

Comment: For OP's use case you'd want `#{i+1}`, but this is a great answer.

Comment: No worries. Your answer is quite elegant.

Comment: I think starting the index from 1 by using `with_index(1)` is better than doing `i+1` in every iteration.

Comment: You don't need `join` here. `puts myArray.map.with_index(1) { ... }` will have the same result.